# Cardinal/ordinal e dois/2?

Tags: significado, diferenças

Estou a tentar perceber a diferença entre *ordinal* e *cardinal*? Qual é?

Estará relacionada com escrever 'dois' ou escrever '2'.

Qualquer ajuda será bem-vinda.

Comment: Estou em dúvida se a tua intenção foi colocar duas perguntas independentes — uma sobre *cardinal/ordinal*, outra sobre o que chamar a escrever *dois* e *2* — num só post; ou as duas perguntas estão relacionadas: por exemplo, se estarás a pensar que *cardinal* corresponde a *dois* e *ordinal* a *2* ou vice-versa. Talvez valesse a pena clarificar, ou separar as duas perguntas. Não há nenhuma regra contra fazer três perguntas num só dia :)

Comment: @Jacinto vou separá-las.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Número cardinal é: 1 (um), 2 (dois), 3 (três), 4 (quatro) etc.

Número ordinal é: 1º (primeiro), 2º (segundo), 3º (terceiro), 4º (quarto) etc.

A diferença entre "2" e "dois" é que o primeiro está escrito com algarismo e o segundo está por extenso.

Comment: escrito por extenso = com palavras

Answer (score 1):

Cardinal: um, dois, três, quatro etc. Ou 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Tanto faz.

Ordinal: primeiro, segundo, terceiro, quarto etc.